# My player falls out when i get his position in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want my camera to follow my player but when i get his position in other script it just falls out[This is the image of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT9yz.png) [the script in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnq6m.png)[Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCOi2.png)[CameraPos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PH6k.png)

PLS HELPP

I only know that if i disable the script nothing happens the camera rotates and it stay in its position

Answer (score 0):

Your plan *should* work, as long as:

1. The CameraPos script is attached to your MainCamera. (make sure!)
2. The "orientation" transform is set to the CameraPos object's transform.(it is)
3. The CameraPos object is a child of the Player (it is)
4. Nothing else is interfering with your MainCamera's position. (make sure!)

The code you've shown is fine – my guess is that if it's a code error, it's in a class that you haven't shown us – especially considering you mentioned your camera was rotating, and the class you screenshotted only applied a position.

Rotation can be really tricky — if you tried the four things I suggested without luck, try sending over your rotation code and we'll see if the problem is there.